# What does the “sd” in “/dev/sdX” stand for?

Tags: filesystem, devices

It seems like the answer might be “SCSI Device” from this thread: [differences between hda to sd0](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/difference-between-dev-hda-to-dev-sd0-567965/). I have been searching for a more concrete link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. `sd*` means SCSI Disk. [Dell has a full glossary available](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ja-jp/000132092/ubuntu-linux-terms-for-your-hard-drive-and-devices-explained) in multiple languages, and this is a page I generally send people to when they have questions about the Linux device naming convention.

In addition to `sd*`, there are:

- `dev/fd*` - Floppy drives
- `dev/scd*` or `/dev/sr*` - SCSI CD-ROMs
- `dev/hd*` - IDE drives
- `dev/mmcblk*` - SDHC card on PCMCIA

Answer (score 0):

I have found a link that I trust more: [NetBSD FAQs](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/kernel/#adding_a_kernel_to_a_boot_floppy)

It states:

> By default, SCSI devices under NetBSD are numbered starting from 0 in the order of SCSI ID number.

---

From this I believe that `sd` stands for SCSI device or SCSI ID. Notice in the first link that this naming convention has been adopted by other devices, including USB and the now rarely used FireWire